# Why do my Angular Services work without specifying them in the provider argument of the @Component annotation?

Tags: angular, angular9

I'm following a Udemy course for angular and the teacher says we need to specify the services we want to import in the providers section of the @Component annotation, to tell Angular which service needs to be injected in this component. But my component works fine without specifying it.

Why is that ?

This is my component

```html
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {AccountService} from "../services/account-service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})
export class AccountComponent {
  @Input() account: {name: string, status: string};
  @Input() id: number;

  constructor(private accountService:AccountService) {
  }

  onSetTo(status: string) {
    this.accountService.updateStatus(this.id,status);
  }
}
```

And this is the service

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {LoggingService} from "./logging.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  accounts = [
    {
      name: 'Master Account',
      status: 'active'
    },
    {
      name: 'Testaccount',
      status: 'inactive'
    },
    {
      name: 'Hidden Account',
      status: 'unknown'
    }
  ];
  constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService) { }

  addAccount(name:string, status:string){
    this.accounts.push({name:name, status:status})
    this.loggingService.logStatusChanged(status)
  }

  updateStatus(id:number,status:string){
    this.accounts[id].status = status;
    this.loggingService.logStatusChanged(status)
  }
}
```

Comment: If the service is included in the `AppModule` or uses `providedIn: 'root'` like your example then it's a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). There is only one instance of it throughout the app and it's available to all the components.

Answer (score 3):

It's working due to the **providedIn: 'root'** available since angular 6, This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root, so available on your components. If the service you want to use is specific to the component then you can provide it specifically at the component level.

Answer (score 2):

The service works because there is two ways of making the service available, in this scenario you have the providedIn defined in the service definition.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

The two ways are:

1. Set the providedIn property of the @Injectable() to "root".
2. Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule.

The first solution you already have it in your code, I will illustrate the second scenario.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [AccountService],
  ...
})
```

I hope this help you to understand why it is working.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to provide a service.

As your service is *providedIn: root* in the *@Injectable* Decorator, it's available at the root of your application so you don't need to reference it somewhere else if you need to access its instance. In such case you don't need to provide it inside a Module or a Component.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a service with `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`,it represents a singleton service service which will have only single instance of it throughout the app.

If you create a service without `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`,it represents a shared service.So in order to inject a shared service within your component, you mention it within `@Component` decorator of that particular component.

That way your component can create a new instance of the service class and access its methods/ variables and it will be within the scope of your component.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular You can inject a service in 3 levels

- Root - A singleton by default
- Module - This also behaves like a root level injection if declared outside the module and is being shared among modules, `@Injectable({providedIn: 'platform'})` or `@Injectable({providedIn: 'any'})` has no effect **Happy to be told otherwice**
- Component - This is full transient behavior where Service instance per Component is created

Refer to the example below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dvrhef